# Why are my Google Data Studio Scheduled Reports Delayed?

Tags: report, delay, schedule, looker-studio

I've been running a couple of weekday Google Data Studio reports for many, many months this year.  They are both scheduled to be delivered via email to their recipients at 6:00 AM every morning (CDT). Typically, they arrive in our Outlook email within about 10 minutes after the 6:00 AM hour each day.

Something changed starting October 26, 2020.  The arrival times are delayed for both reports by over an hour (1:44, 1:23, 1:19, 1:03) to be exact.  I changed both reports' schedules to arrive at 3:30 AM versus 6:00 AM. Still, they arrived an hour and 3 minutes later than scheduled.

Do you have any suggestions as to where to probe for the change which triggered these delays?  It it our system? Is it somewhere within the Google's stack?  Daylight savings time change triggered somewhere?

I provided a log of my experience with these delays for additional context.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: [As of REVISION 2] **Not Reproducible**: This looks like it was a temporary issue that affected some users and is no longer reproducible (note: I didn't face the issue at the time and have not faced this specific issue since)... Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to visualise and pinpoint a suggestion to a specific use case

Answer (score -1):

On Sunday, October 25th happened the annual switch from daylight saving time to standard time. Maybe this explains the delay?

Comment: Note that the answer is speculative and in any case, the issue is **Not Reproducible**: This looks like it was a temporary issue that affected some users and is no longer reproducible (note: I didn't face the issue at the time and have not faced this specific issue since)... Without a link to a specific source that clarified on the issue, the answer is better suited as a comment....